# issue with web view and overriding links

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in which some parts of it have an `<a href="" > <img src="" </a>` in it. I have added a UITapGesture to this UIWebView and so what I want is basically when a user taps on an image, it doesn't bring you to the link pointed to it but rather do something. I am having issues in preventing the image to go to the hyperlink it's pointed to. Any idea? I've tried injecting javascript so that it changes the href to some fake link when the user taps the image and then on the:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

I checked the request url if that matches the dummy I have. However, this doesn't work, for some reason changing the href link using:

```
NSString *stripLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href=%@", pt.x, pt.y, @"http://www.fakeurl.com"];
    if ([self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:stripLink] != nil){
        NSString *testHref = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href", pt.x, pt.y];
        NSLog(@"FINAL HREF IS %@", [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:testHref]);
    }
```

any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the HTML source (and it sounds like you do?), then you can change the href to use a custom URI scheme, e.g. photo://  then you can do the following:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"photo"])
    {
         // Custom Handling Goes Here
         return NO;  // Stops the link being executed by UIWebView
    } else
         return YES;
}
```

If, however, you cannot control the HTML source, then you may need to be slightly more devious.  E.g. you could check the end of the path and see if it's an image (jpg, png etc...)

Comment: well, the issue is that I don't know which of the url will be pressed by the user, that's why I had the javascript function above in my touch handler to change the link of the image I touch to something else, but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve then, maybe you can describe the use case?  If you change all of the links then they'll all come to your custom handling code - and you can do something different depending on the rest of the URI?

Comment: I mean, I don't think your TapGesture needs to be part of the solution - get rid of that, and then do your custom action as a result of processing the different URLs in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:...` e.g. photo://image1 photo://image2 photo://image3 - you can handle them all differently (if that's what you want to do...)

Comment: well initially the HTML source has the image linked to some form of other links... I need to first replace this with the custom link (photo://image1). How do I change all of the image links to something like this?

Comment: also the reason I want to do the touch is because replacing all occurences of images in the first hand before loading the html is going to be an overhead, if I'd just replace for that particular image when I do the touch on the image, it is more efficient that way. That's why I have the tap gesture

Comment: Just to be clear then - you don't have control over the HTML source, and you're looking to perform a custom action when the user touches a link on an existing page.  Are you just wanting this custom action when the link has an image inside it?  I see from the other questions you've posted that you're executing some Javascript on the page to try and find the coordinates of the images?  Maybe instead you could pull out the URLs that they link to, store those in an NSSet and then check the set in `webView:shouldStartLoad...`

Comment: also to clarify the href linked to the <a href=> doesn't have some form of pattern.. so it's hard for me to do some matching in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest. I'd first have to replace this link with photo:// and then I can detect that in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest. This is also an issue I have

Comment: I can store the link that it points out to in a set, but this is an additional storage cost.. the most efficient way I think is to replace that link with photo://image1 and then I could detect photo://image1 in the webView:shouldStartLoad... don't you kind of agree? That replacing is better than storing the NSURL?

Comment: Either way works, although I wouldn't personally worry about a handful of NSURLs.  I guess it ultimately depends on whether running JS to replace the links is significantly faster or slower than running JS to extract the links.

Comment: yes, can you then help me why replacing that url with javascript I have doesn't work? it doesn't seem to change the href link, stays with the old one

Comment: Sorry, my javascript knowledge is non-existent.  However I'd probably start by looking at the difference between CSS coordinate-space and the pt.x, pt.y coordinate-space and making sure that I've got that right...